# BluetoothServerSocket is not accepting Bluetoothsocket on some devices

Tags: java, android

I want to connect as a server from my device to client's device. In my application I am using following AcceptThread class:

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        try {                
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket's listen() method failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;            
    }

    public void run() {           
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        while (true) {               
            try {                    
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();                    
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket's accept() method failed", e);
                break;
            }                

            if (socket != null) {
                manageMyConnectedSocket(socket);
                try {
                    mmServerSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works well in Samsung Galaxy J3.
But on Samsung Galaxy S6 and Lenovo Tab3 10 the application is stopped on line **socket = mmServerSocket.accept();** 
On Lenovo Tab I get following error:

```
Socket's accept() method failed
java.io.IOException: Try again
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.-wrap3(LocalSocketImpl.java)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:101)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:688)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.waitSocketSignal(BluetoothSocket.java:649)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:463)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:158)
```

Both Samsung phones has Android 7.0.

What can be on Samsung S6 blocking to accept Bluetooth socket?

Comment: Did you find out any reason? any solution

Comment: No.I didn't find solution.